# Поток Thread, Java(Netbeans) или C++(Visual studio)

Tags: java, c++

**Задача**: Разделить на 2 потока (`Thread`) код линейного конгруэнтного метода для генераций псевдослучайных чисел (например 100000 чисел).

Код без потока уже имеется.

Не могу понять: как и что именно разделить на два потока, еще надо увеличить посещаемость чисел, то есть память(например, чтоб в переменную а поместилось такие большие числа как 6463136223846793005)

```
package javaapplication;
public class JavaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=1664525, c=1013904223;
        int m;
        m=(int)Math.pow(2,32);
        int arr[] = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) { arr[0]=1;
        arr[i+1]=(a*arr[i-1]+c)%m;
        System.out.println(arr[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А кто перед вами поставил такую задачу? И зачем разделять генерацию на несколько потоков? Ведь в линейном конгруэнтном генераторе следующий результат зависит от предыдущего, поэтому генерация должна быть синхронизирована, так что особой выгоды от распараллеливания вы не полуите (при условии что вам необходимо сохранить корректность генерации).

Comment: `arr[0]=1;` - это зря в цикле.

Comment: @fori1ton, согласен, что задачка странноватая, но в принципе выигрыш может быть в отсутствии синхронизации между потоками (естественно, для случая, когда для получения очередного числа вызываем что-то вроде `my_rand()`, а не заполняем массив). Т.е. если мы знаем, что у нас именно 2 потока (и умеем их различать), то можно представить код, который при очередном вызове вычисляет и возвращает для одного потока числа,, соответствующие четным индексам, а для другого нечетным.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, нужно отделить основной поток программы от потока вычислений.
Если так, пишем вычисления в отдельный класс.

```
class MyRunner implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
        int a=1664525, c=1013904223, m=(int)Math.pow(2,32);
        int arr[] = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) { 
           arr[0]=1;
           arr[i+1]=(a*arr[i-1]+c)%m;
           System.out.println(arr[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

И вызываем его в главном методе:

```
public class JavaApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyRunner myRunner = new MyRunner(); 
      Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunner);
      myThread.start();
   }
}
```

Если нет - посмотрите как работает, например, Fork-Join - http://www.developer.com/java/java-7-forkjoin-framework.html